# Where is the dom attribute Template.content documented?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The template element is documented in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).
In the 2nd example code block (Quoted below), they use the `.content` attribute.

```
var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
```

Where is `template.content` documented? And what is it's browser support.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content It's a property, though, not a method. Also, there's no example of `content` method in the article you've linked. In that example `template.content` is passed as an argument to `document.importNode` method.

Comment: Follow the link to ''DOM Interface'' HTMLTemplateElement, which contains the [content property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content); it is not a function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, updated question to reflect that it is an attribute not a function. If you answer will mark as correct.